# Write Regkey if NIC DNS is true

Tags: powershell, dns

I am attempting to write a regkey via powershell if a certain parameter is true. That being, the DNS Primary address is 192.192.192.192 (for the NIC that already has the DNS entry).

Here's what I have:

```
$adapters = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object 
{$_.DNSServerSearchOrder -cmatch "192.192.192.192"} 

If ($_.DNSServerSearchOrder -cmatch "192.192.192.192")  

{

New-Item -Path HKCU:\System\CurrentDNS\DNS -Value "192.192.192.192"

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but this should work.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration|%{`
if($_.DNSServerSearchOrder){`
   $_.DNSServerSearchOrder|%{`
      if($_ -match "192.192.192.192"){`
         New-Item -Path HKCU:\System\CurrentDNS\DNS -Value "192.192.192.192"
      }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: What's with the backticks for line continuations? There's no need for that unless you have a line that PS would normally expect to be a single statement; opening a new block without closing it certainly would not count.